# Is it possible to keep a button's label alternating between values until it is clicked?

Tags: android, button, label

For example, a button would be labeled with digits from 0 to 9, one at a time and changing at a given rate (say, each half a second). When clicked, the label would stop changing and be set to the value showing at the time. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You could use a `Handler` (Java) or a coroutine (Kotlin) to do this. Here are some examples:

**Kotlin**

With Kotlin, you can start a coroutine that has a loop with a delay, and when the button is clicked it exits the loop and stops updating the button text and stored number.

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.timedBtn.setOnClickListener { incrementing = false }
    startNumbers()
}

private var incrementing = true
private var num = 0
private val delayMillisecond = 500L

private fun startNumbers() {
    incrementing = true
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        while(incrementing) {
            num = (num + 1) % 10
            binding.timedBtn.text = "$num"
            delay(delayMillisecond)
        }
    }
}
```

**Java**

With Java you can use a handler and `postDelayed` to keep posting future updates to the button text, and when the button is pressed cancel all the handler tasks so it stops updating the button text and stored number.

```java
private ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    
    binding.timedBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null));
    startNumbers();
}

private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private int num = 0;
private final long delay_ms = 500;

private void startNumbers() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            num = (num + 1) % 10;
            binding.timedBtn.setText(String.valueOf(num));
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay_ms);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried the Java handler, works perfectly. Thanks!